# How to convert control.background(brush) to bitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, brush

How to convert system.windows.controls.control.background(brush) to bitmap?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public BitmapSource ConvertToBitmapSource(UIElement element)
{
    var target = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(element.RenderSize.Width), (int)(element.RenderSize.Height), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    var brush = new VisualBrush(element);

    var visual = new DrawingVisual();
    var drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen();


    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(element.RenderSize.Width, element.RenderSize.Height)));

    drawingContext.Close();

    target.Render(visual);

    return target;
}
```

Comment: This does not work correctly when the size of the control is greater than 2048x2048. The picture is blurry.

MSDN about `BitmapCache`: "The cache functions when hardware acceleration is not available. In this case, the bitmap is rendered in software, and the maximum bitmap dimensions are 2048 x 2048."

Does anyone know how to increase the cache to the desired size?